# "to pose" or "to posit" a problem

Tags: synonyms, formality

On the context of technical literature I have seen both of the mentioned verbs to introduce a problem formally.

Is there any nuance between them or they can be indistinguishably used?

The exact phrase I am interested on would be something like the following:

"The problem is [posed]/[posited] as a numerical optimization over..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two words have different meanings:

> ***[Posit](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/posit)***
>
> VERB
>
> 1. *[with object]* Assume as a fact; put forward as a basis of argument.
>      *‘the Confucian view posits a perfectible human nature’*
>
>    *[with clause]* ‘he posited that the world economy is a system with its own particular equilibrium’
>
>    1.1 (**posit something on**) Base something on the truth of (a particular assumption)
>      *‘these plots are posited on a false premise about women's nature as inferior’*

versus

> ***[Pose](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/pose)***
>
> VERB
>
> 1. *[with object]* Present or constitute (a problem, danger, or difficulty)
>      *‘the sheer number of visitors is posing a threat to the area’*
>
>    1.1 Raise (a question or matter for consideration)
>      *‘a statement that posed more questions than it answered’*

So, *posit* means to make a statement as if it were true, understanding that others might challenge that statement.  One might, for example, ***posit*** that *all politicians are corrupt*, a position with which others might agree or disagree.  If someone did disagree, one might then ***pose*** the challenge that they find a single example of a politician who was not corrupt.

Does that make sense?

Comment: Yeah, I've always understood "posit" to mean "conjecture", while "pose" is simply "present".

Comment: I remember it as _posit_ is your _**posit**ion_ while _pose_ is what you do when you present yourself to the world (something my daughter does 24/7.)